# How do I select a button before text using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a bit of a dilemma.  I have a table of 3 columns. Column 1 is a button to make that row active.  The 2nd column is the name of the person.  And the 3rd column is a button to view the person's details.

Using Selenium C#, I can search for a specific person in the table and click the button to View, using the code below:

```
currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Name of person'])")).Click();
```

How do I select the button before the name of the person?

EDIT:  Added HTML -

```
<table class="table table-hover>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody id="listCompany">
<tr>
<td>
<span id="a5" class="badge btnActivateCompany clsActiveCompany15" ><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span> 
</td>
<td>Test Director</td>
<td>
 <button.>...</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The class btnActivateCompany is used several times depending on how many rows exist.  And the id changes depending on the rows as well.  So I have to search to find the correct record and then select the span before it.
I tried the following to select the object:

```
currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Test Director'])[1]/preceding::span[1]")).Click();
```

Comment: Without seeing the table/rows its hard to say, but if you have already found the person, then you need to search for the row (<tr>) for that person, then you can search for the relevant column (<td>).

Comment: If you can't identify the buttom directly You want to use then preceding:: xpath method. Do you have some html or a link so I can be more helpful?

Comment: add your HTML please so the community can Help

Comment: Can you please edit and add it into the question? - a string like that is difficult to process

Comment: Thanks @RichEdwards.  I am still learning how to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you've modified the HTML as you've posted. I guess you stripped out some data and typed other content in.  You say you want the button before the person, but in your code the button is after the person?

Either way, both are achievable. I made a few quick additions to help visibility. If i'm wrong please correct me as it influences xpaths.

Quick change log: I ran your html through a beautifier, added text to all the columns for visibility, added `"border=1"` to the table, remove the `.` from button, added the `</table>` and duplicated the row so i can check unique objects are found.

This is the result:  *(useful if anyone else wants to chip in an identifier)*

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-hover" border=1>
            <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody id="listCompany">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="a5" class="badge btnActivateCompany clsActiveCompany15" >
                            <i class="fas fa-times"> Column 1</i>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Test Director</td>
                    <td>
                        <button> Button in col 3
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="a5" class="badge btnActivateCompany clsActiveCompany15" >
                            <i class="fas fa-times"> Column 1</i>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Second Row!</td>
                    <td>
                        <button> Button in col 3
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

That renders like this:

[image: html table]

Based on fact you say you can get the text in the middle column...

If you want the button in column 3, you can try xpath:

```
//td[text()='Test Director']/parent::*/td/button
```

If you want the span in column 1, you can try:

```
//td[text()='Test Director']/parent::*/td/span[contains(@class,'btnActivateCompany')]
```

In both of these instances this selects a unique hit in the source.

However, please note, this is dependent on the html provided. If there are other elements/attributes in the table the xpath might need more work. I'm happy to help more but you'll need to share more content.